# Pystan -- Library\\mingw-w64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1

Tags: python, pystan

I would like to test orbit-ml package but I have same issues with pystan
My settings are: Windows10, Anacaonda, Python 3.7 (or 3.8)
When I run this demo code:

```
import pystan
model_code = 'parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}'
model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)
y = model.sampling().extract()['y']
y.mean()  # with luck the result will be near 0
```

I had this error: CompileError: command 'C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\envs\orbit-ml-py37\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1

I installed orbit-ml following the official documentantion.
I had problem with pystan (MSVC compiler is not supported) and I followed step by step the documentation [link](https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html)

After that no warning on MSVC but the code stops with this error:

CompileError: command 'C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\envs\orbit-ml-py37\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1

I don't understand. Do you have any suggestions?
All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some dependency related problem. Solving this could be a hard thing. You can refer this [Documentation](https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html)

If you want to get started, try the following

**Observations**

From your code snippet, I have observed the following:

1. `import pystan` does not work in recent versions (as per [reference](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html))
2. There could be issues with `StanModel` in the library. Check [reference](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html)

**Suggestions**

Few alternatives to get to started with other approaches by bypassing the process are:

1. Try google colab to get started. Go to [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com) and experiment there
2. Try a linux/ubuntu VM using docker and install there.

[image]